# Imageview in my app

Tags: java, android

I want to show an image when certain condition is met in the code.
My code is:

```
if((times-prt)/1000000 >1000) {
                prt=times;
                pushdata((lightIn > 150 ? 1 : 0));
                // Log.d("Light amount: %02f", lightIn+"getArraydata= "+getArraydata() +"getArraydata()"+matchPattern());
                if(matchPattern()) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_logo);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_logo);

                    // finish();
                    // System.exit(0);
                }
            }
```

Pattern is matching but no picture is showing.
Please, help me.

Comment: comment out if (matchPattern()) and the end bracket to see if it is indeed showing.

Answer (score 0):

If your image view has visibility set to INVISIBLE or GONE in your layout.xml file, you will also need to call:

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```